# Disabling and Enabling a button on event iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a stopclock app and would like for the `startCountButton` button to be disabled when it is initially pressed and then once the `stopCountButton` button is pressed for it to be enabled again so that the start button can only be pressed once. Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)startCount:(UIButton*)sender {
    countInt = 0;
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)stopCount:(UIButton*)sender {
    countInt = 0;
    [timer invalidate];
}

-(void)countTimer {
    countInt += 1;
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
}
```

Any help on what I would need to add? I am not looking to change text, just disabling it

Comment: What's your question? What is preventing you from doing what you are stating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need a reference to the button. Then, add the following code to `startCount:`:

```
((UIButton *)sender).enabled = NO
```

and in `stopCount:` add:

```
startCountButton.enabled = YES
```

Comment: When I add this two lines, I get the following error message: `Use of undeclared identifier 'startCount'`

Comment: @peterbonar What? Those two lines do not have the word `startCount` in them. What did you add?

Comment: The button is not called `startButton`

Comment: Yes, the button is also called `startCount`

Comment: I have already said above that it produces an error message

Comment: @peterbonar Rename your buttons `startCountButton` & `stopCountButton`.  That's much more in-line with Obj-C naming standards & best practices.

Comment: @peterbonar Have you added a reference to the button, as I wrote in my answer? If so, show the code with the reference. If not, do it.

Comment: Got it, thanks @dasdom

Answer (score 1):

Both `startCount:` and `stopCount:` accept a `UIButton` as their parameter, but I'm confused as to how the second one gets called.

If `startCount:` is called by the button you want to disable, you can just write this:

```
sender.enabled = NO;
```

But `stopCount:` is tricky, because clearly it can't be called by the button as it was disabled a moment ago. If `stopCount:` is being called from a different button (as I guess it must be) then you must store a reference to the first button in order to re-enable it. You can then do:

```
self.disabledButton.enabled = YES;
```

Comment: `enabled` is better because (depending on the button type used) it fades out the button as well.

Comment: Ha! I was just making that exact change :)

Answer (score 0):

With `enable` propriety you can enable/disable a button:

```
startCountButton.enabled = NO
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the appropriate language.